# iPhone SDK dismiss actionsheet and present image gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, gallery

I'm building this app and have been pretty successful. However, I just recently wanted to change the way a user picks to upload an image. It's now with an actionsheet. The problem is that when a button is clicked I try and dismiss the actionsheet then start up the image gallery, but it won't work. Thanks for your help!

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


///////////

  UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]

                                  initWithTitle:@"Submit Photo"

                                  delegate:self

                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"

                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil

                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo",@"Select Photo from Gallery", nil];

    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: What won't work? Please be specific about what the problem is.

Comment: It doesn't dismiss and it just freezes.

Comment: Did you set your class where this code is to be the delegate of the action sheet?

Comment: Show the code where you created the action sheet.

Comment: Did you pass `self` as the delegate to the action sheet when you created it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method, implement the `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method. Then you don't need to dismiss the action sheet yourself.

And make sure you pass `self` as the delegate to the action sheet when you create it.